# Get the url of attachments from the post?

Tags: plugins, database

I used the following code to get the images attached to a post

```
    $current_id = get_the_ID();
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results("select guid from $wpdb->posts where post_parent = $current_id");

    foreach ($rows as $row) {

    ?>

        <a href="<?php echo $row->guid; ?>" data-titan-lightbox="on" data-titan-group="<?php the_ID() ?>"  style="display: none"><img src="<?php echo $row->guid; ?>" alt="Caption" class="Thumbnail thumbnail " width="228" height="160"></a>

    <?php
```

but this code only gives the images path with the folder containing the images.

How can I get only the images from this loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about it the wrong way.

You can use `get_posts` to get the attachments of the current post:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' =>'any', 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo apply_filters( 'the_title' , $attachment->post_title );
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
    }
}
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_attachments_for_the_current_post

Comment: Did you figure this out, @osos?